# ScaleTransform for Local Objects GDI+

Tags: c++, gdi+

I want to change the direction of the Y axis only for one object. I create the Pen object and apply the method .ScaleTransform(1, -1). But the line is not inverted (the problem is in the red line).

```
void OnPaint(HDC hdc, const RECT &rc)
{
    Graphics graphics(hdc);
    graphics.SetPageUnit(UnitPixel);
    graphics.TranslateTransform(25, 180);

    Pen pen(Color(255, 0, 0, 0), 1.0f);
    graphics.DrawLine(&pen, -500, 0, 1000, 0);

    pen.SetColor(Color(255, 255, 0, 0));
    pen.ScaleTransform(1, -1);
    graphics.DrawLine(&pen, 10, -50, 500, -50);
}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Hmm, you are scaling a solid color pen - this will not produce any visible effect.

Comment: @KlausGütter Why is this method not working? How to solve my problem?